# How can I sort the second dropdown list by date to have the newest page title the first?

Tags: php, concrete5

```
<?php
foreach ($navItems as $ni) {
?>

<li class="<?php echo $ni->classes ?><?php echo($ni->hasSubmenu)?" dropdown":""; ?>">

   <?php
   if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {                         
   ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $ni->url; ?>" target="<?php echo $ni->target; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle <?php echo $ni->classes; ?>" data-toggle="mydropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo (isset($translate) && $translate == true) ? t($ni->date) : $ni->name; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>

     <?php
     } else{
     ?>

<a href="<?php echo $ni->url; ?>" target="<?php echo $ni->target; ?>" class="<?php echo $ni->classes; ?>"><?php echo (isset($translate) && $translate == true) ? t($ni->name) : $ni->name; ?></a>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
 <?php
    if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {
       echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'; //opens a dropdown sub-menu
   } else {
      echo '</li>'; //closes a nav item
      echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $ni->subDepth); //closes dropdown sub-menu(s) and their top-level nav item(s)
   }
   ?>
</li>
 <?php
 }
```

[image]

I want that "Szelíd beszéd" on the top, that is the newest added to the page.

Comment: Why don't you use mysql's order() command to order by date? I.e. SELECT * FROM menus ORDER BY date DESC

Comment: $foo = $db->GetALL('SELECT * FROM CollectionVersions WHERE pTemplateID = 9 ORDER BY cvDatePublic desc', [$id]); how can I use this for the submenu ?

Comment: I have it before 

<?php
foreach ($navItems as $ni) {
?>

Answer (score 0):

As Concrete5 returns a single array of objects rather than a nested array, you can't tell what is a child and what isn't until you loop through it.

As such, I would suggest you rebuild the nav items array, and when you get to those items, append a page list of them and then continue.

This may not work, as you would lose references on those pages for the likes of 'hasSubmenu' or 'subDepth' but give it a go.

```
<?php

$navItemsNew = array();
$addedOrderedList = false;
$parentID = 4; //replace 4 with the ID of the parent page

foreach ($navItems as $ni) {
  if($ni->cObj->getCollectionParentId() == $parentID){ 
    if($addedOrderedList){
      continue;
    }else{
      $pl = new PageList();
      $pl->filterByParentID($parentID); //Get all posts beneath that parent
      $pl->sortByPublicDate(); // Sort by public date, newest first
      $pl->setItemsPerPage(0); //return all items in 1 page
      $posts = $pl->getPage(1);
      $addedOrderedList = true;
      array_merge($navItemsNew, $posts);
      continue;
    }
  }
  $navItemsNew[] = $ni;
}


foreach ($navItemsNew as $ni) {
?>

<li class="<?php echo $ni->classes ?><?php echo($ni->hasSubmenu)?" dropdown":""; ?>">

   <?php
   if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {                         
   ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $ni->url; ?>" target="<?php echo $ni->target; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle <?php echo $ni->classes; ?>" data-toggle="mydropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo (isset($translate) && $translate == true) ? t($ni->date) : $ni->name; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>

     <?php
     } else{
     ?>

<a href="<?php echo $ni->url; ?>" target="<?php echo $ni->target; ?>" class="<?php echo $ni->classes; ?>"><?php echo (isset($translate) && $translate == true) ? t($ni->name) : $ni->name; ?></a>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
 <?php
    if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {
       echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'; //opens a dropdown sub-menu
   } else {
      echo '</li>'; //closes a nav item
      echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $ni->subDepth); //closes dropdown sub-menu(s) and their top-level nav item(s)
   }
   ?>
</li>
 <?php
 }
```

Comment: Note: array_merge may not be the best bet here, if you find pages go missing, try a foreach to just push them onto the end.

Answer (score -1):

The pages in submenu comes from xml, from another website, tomorow  will be added  1 new page ..and will show us in in autonav last child...but we need first!